# jCarousel next and prev button, disable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Im using http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ as a slider....
It shows one image at a time, and a total of four images... When displaying the first image, i dont want the prev arrow to be visible, and the same if im at number 4 image, i dont want the next arrow to be visible...

How do i do this?

I initialize the script like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
                            });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the arrows.  Adding the disabled classes is handled by the plugin itself.

```
.jcarousel-prev-disabled, .jcarousel-next-disabled
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ubanC/88/

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat by using two below options:

1. Using CSS,you should override to set some below classes:

   ```
   <style>
   jcarousel-prev-disabled,
   jcarousel-next-disabled,
   jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal,
   jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal{
       background-position:0 0;
   }
   </style>
   ```
2. Using Javascript, this solution is same as the first. We should remove the classes: `disable` for `next` and `previous` buttons:

   ```
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
           itemFirstOutCallback: {
               onBeforeAnimation: function(){

               },
               onAfterAnimation: function(){
                   $(".jcarousel-prev").removeClass("jcarousel-prev-disabled");
                   $(".jcarousel-prev").removeClass("jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal");
               }
           },
           itemLastOutCallback: {
               onBeforeAnimation: function(){

               },
               onAfterAnimation: function(){
                   $(".jcarousel-next").removeClass("jcarousel-next-disabled");
                   $(".jcarousel-next").removeClass("jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal");
               }
           }
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

P/S: I just try to read it's document and use `Firebug`(~Edit on the fly) to detect. If you could, you can try. It's fun.

Comment: Don't know why this isn't the chosen answer - it's far more comprehensive!